# How to make a multi-column acronym list with acro package, aligned and with short definition in bold?

Tags: tables, formatting, multicol, acronyms, acro

I want to fix the alignment issue so that the long definitions are all aligned. I've pasted the relevant code I used to generate the example below. I've also got a second attempt where I've got it looking good but it only works with 1 column. Thanks in advance.

Attempt1:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=25mm, bottom=27mm, left=35mm, right=30mm, bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[hyperref = true, only-used = false, list-style = longtable]{acro}

%Some other packages I use. 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{enumitem} %allows itemize environment adjustments
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} %load after hyperref
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{palatino} %FONT
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% Tables
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}


%%% Nomenclature Definitions

%%% Acronyms
\DeclareAcronym{ADC}{
    short = ADC,
    long  = Analogue to Digital Converter,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{AE}{
    short = AE,
    long  = Acoustic Emission,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{AI}{
    short = AI,
    long  = Artificial Intelligence,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{ANN}{
    short = ANN,
    long  = Artificial Neural Network,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{ACTMS}{
    short = ACTMS,
    long  = Acoustic Combustion Turbine Monitoring System,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{ASIC}{
    short = ASIC,
    long  = Application Specific Integrated Circuit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{BLDC}{
    short = BLDC,
    long  = BrushLess Direct Current,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{CWT}{
    short = CWT,
    long  = Continuous Wavelet Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DAC}{
    short = DAC,
    long  = Digital to Analogue Converter,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DFT}{
    short = DFT,
    long  = Discrete Fourier Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DSP}{
    short = DSP,
    long  = Digital Signal Processing / Processor,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DWT}{
    short = DWT,
    long  = Discrete Wavelet Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{EEMD}{
    short = EEMD,
    long  = Ensemble Empirical Mode Decomposition,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{EMD}{
    short = EMD,
    long  = Empirical Mode Decomposition,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{EMI}{
    short = EMI,
    long  = Electromagnetic Interference,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{FFT}{
    short = FFT,
    long  = Fast Fourier Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{FPGA}{
    short = FPGA,
    long  = Field-Programmable Gate Array,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{FTF}{
    short = FTF,
    long  = Fundamental Train Frequency,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{GenPU}{
    short = GPU,
    long  = General Processing Unit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{GraPU}{
    short = GPU,
    long  = Graphics Processing Unit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{HDL}{
    short = HDL,
    long  = Hardware Description Language,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{HHT}{
    short = HHT,
    long  = Hilbert-Huang Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{IDE}{
    short = IDE,
    long  = Integrated Development Environment,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{IMF}{
    short = IMF,
    long  = Intrinsic Mode Function,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{MCSA}{
    short = MCSA,
    long  = Motor Current Signature Analysis,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{PCA}{
    short = PCA,
    long  = Principal Component Analysis,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{PWM}{
    short = PWM,
    long  = Pulse Width Modulation,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{REB}{
    short = REB,
    long  = Roller Element Bearing,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RFI}{
    short = RFI,
    long  = Radio Frequency Interference,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RMS}{
    short = RMS,
    long  = Root Mean Square,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RPFI}{
    short = RPFI,
    long  = Roller Pass Frequency Inner-Race,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RPFO}{
    short = RPFO,
    long  = Roller Pass Frequency Outer-Race,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RSF}{
    short = RSF,
    long  = Roller Spin Frequency,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{SDSoC}{
    short = SDSoC,
    long  = Software Defined System on Chip,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{SoC}{
    short = SoC,
    long  = System on Chip,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{STFT}{
    short = STFT,
    long  = Short-Time Fourier Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{SVM}{
    short = SVM,
    long  = Support Vector Machine,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{VLSI}{
    short = VLSI,
    long  = Very Large Scale Integration,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{VHDL}{
    short = VHDL,
    long  = VHSIC Hardware Description Language,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{VHSIC}{
    short = VHSIC,
    long  = Very High Speed Integrated Circuit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{WPT}{
    short = WPT,
    long  = Wavelet Packet Transform,
    class = abbrev}

%%% Symbols

%% Regular Alphabet
\DeclareAcronym{b}{
    short = \ensuremath{b},
    long  = Dyadic Translation,
    sort  = 0002,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{c}{
    short = \ensuremath{c},
    long  = Speed of Sound,
    sort  = 0003,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{EffElas}{
    short = \ensuremath{E},
    long  = Effective Elastic Modulus,
    sort  = 0005,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{g}{
    short = \ensuremath{g},
    long  = High-Pass Filter (Wavelet Transform),
    sort  = 0007,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{h}{
    short = \ensuremath{h},
    long  = Low-Pass Filter (Wavelet Transform),
    sort  = 0008,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Ks}{
    short = \ensuremath{K_{s}},
    long  = Bulk Modulus,
    sort  = 0011,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{m}{
    short = \ensuremath{m},
    long  = Mass,
    sort  = 0012,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{M}{
    short = \ensuremath{M},
    long  = Molecular Mass,
    sort  = 0012.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{P}{
    short = \ensuremath{P},
    long  = Pressure,
    sort  = 0015,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{CPV}{
    short = \ensuremath{CPV},
    long  = Cauchy Principle Value,
    sort  = 0015.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{v}{
    short = \ensuremath{v},
    long  = Velocity,
    sort  = 0021,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{V}{
    short = \ensuremath{V},
    long  = Volume,
    sort  = 0021.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Wab}{
    short = \ensuremath{W_{(\alpha,b)}},
    long  = Wavelet Coefficients,
    sort  = 0022,
    class = nomencl}

%% Greek Alphabet
\DeclareAcronym{alpha}{
    short = \ensuremath{\alpha},
    long  = Dyadic Dilation,
    sort  = 1001,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{beta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\beta},
    long  = Beta,
    sort  = 1002,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{gamma}{
    short = \ensuremath{\gamma},
    long  = Heat Capacity Ratio,
    sort  = 1003,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{delta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\delta},
    long  = Delta,
    sort  = 1004,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{epsilon}{
    short = \ensuremath{\epsilon},
    long  = Epsilon,
    sort  = 1005,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varepsilon}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varepsilon},
    long  = Varepsilon,
    sort  = 1006,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{zeta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\zeta},
    long  = Zeta,
    sort  = 1007,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{eta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\eta},
    long  = Eta,
    sort  = 1008,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{theta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\theta},
    long  = Angle,
    sort  = 1009,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{vartheta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\vartheta},
    long  = Vartheta,
    sort  = 1010,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Theta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\Theta},
    long  = Cap Theta,
    sort  = 1011,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{iota}{
    short = \ensuremath{\iota},
    long  = Iota,
    sort  = 1012,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{kappa}{
    short = \ensuremath{\kappa},
    long  = Kappa,
    sort  = 1013,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{lambda}{
    short = \ensuremath{\lambda},
    long  = Wavelength,
    sort  = 1014,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Lambda}{
    short = \ensuremath{\Lambda},
    long  = Lambda,
    sort  = 1015,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{mu}{
    short = \ensuremath{\mu},
    long  = mu,
    sort  = 1016,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{nu}{
    short = \ensuremath{\nu},
    long  = nu,
    sort  = 1017,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{xi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\xi},
    long  = xi,
    sort  = 1018,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{rho}{
    short = \ensuremath{\rho},
    long  = Density,
    sort  = 1021,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varrho}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varrho},
    long  = varrho,
    sort  = 1022,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{sigma}{
    short = \ensuremath{\sigma},
    long  = sigma,
    sort  = 1023,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varsigma}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varsigma},
    long  = varsigma,
    sort  = 1024,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{tau}{
    short = \ensuremath{\tau},
    long  = tau,
    sort  = 1025,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{upsilon}{
    short = \ensuremath{\upsilon},
    long  = upsilon,
    sort  = 1026,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{phi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\phi},
    long  = phi,
    sort  = 1027,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varphiphase}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varphi},
    long  = Phase,
    sort  = 1028,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varphiwavelet}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varphi},
    long  = Dyadic Dilation Function,
    sort  = 1028.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varPhi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varPhi},
    long  = varPhi,
    sort  = 1029,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{chi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\chi},
    long  = chi,
    sort  = 1030,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{psi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\psi},
    long  = Analysing Wavelet / Mother Wavelet,
    sort  = 1031,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varPsi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varPsi},
    long  = varPsi,
    sort  = 1032,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{omega}{
    short = \ensuremath{\omega},
    long  = Angular Frequency,
    sort  = 1033,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Omega}{
    short = \ensuremath{\Omega},
    long  = Omega,
    sort  = 1034,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varOmega}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varOmega},
    long  = varOmega,
    sort  = 1035,
    class = nomencl}



\begin{document}

    \chapter*{Nomenclature}

    \section*{Abbreviations}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{footnotesize}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev, heading=none]
            \end{multicols}
        \end{footnotesize}
    \end{flushleft}

    \newpage
    \section*{Characters \& Symbols}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{footnotesize}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl, heading=none]
            \end{multicols}
        \end{footnotesize}
    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Attempt 1]

Attempt 2:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=25mm, bottom=27mm, left=35mm, right=30mm, bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[hyperref = true, only-used = false]{acro}
\usepackage{tabu,longtable}
\DeclareAcroListStyle{longtabu}{table}{
    table = longtabu ,
    table-spec = @{}>{\bfseries}lX@{}}
\acsetup{list-style=longtabu}

%Some other packages I use. 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{enumitem} %allows itemize environment adjustments
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} %load after hyperref
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{palatino} %FONT
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% Tables
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}


%%% Nomenclature Definitions

%%% Acronyms
\DeclareAcronym{ADC}{
    short = ADC,
    long  = Analogue to Digital Converter,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{AE}{
    short = AE,
    long  = Acoustic Emission,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{AI}{
    short = AI,
    long  = Artificial Intelligence,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{ANN}{
    short = ANN,
    long  = Artificial Neural Network,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{ACTMS}{
    short = ACTMS,
    long  = Acoustic Combustion Turbine Monitoring System,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{ASIC}{
    short = ASIC,
    long  = Application Specific Integrated Circuit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{BLDC}{
    short = BLDC,
    long  = BrushLess Direct Current,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{CWT}{
    short = CWT,
    long  = Continuous Wavelet Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DAC}{
    short = DAC,
    long  = Digital to Analogue Converter,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DFT}{
    short = DFT,
    long  = Discrete Fourier Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DSP}{
    short = DSP,
    long  = Digital Signal Processing / Processor,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DWT}{
    short = DWT,
    long  = Discrete Wavelet Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{EEMD}{
    short = EEMD,
    long  = Ensemble Empirical Mode Decomposition,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{EMD}{
    short = EMD,
    long  = Empirical Mode Decomposition,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{EMI}{
    short = EMI,
    long  = Electromagnetic Interference,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{FFT}{
    short = FFT,
    long  = Fast Fourier Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{FPGA}{
    short = FPGA,
    long  = Field-Programmable Gate Array,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{FTF}{
    short = FTF,
    long  = Fundamental Train Frequency,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{GenPU}{
    short = GPU,
    long  = General Processing Unit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{GraPU}{
    short = GPU,
    long  = Graphics Processing Unit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{HDL}{
    short = HDL,
    long  = Hardware Description Language,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{HHT}{
    short = HHT,
    long  = Hilbert-Huang Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{IDE}{
    short = IDE,
    long  = Integrated Development Environment,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{IMF}{
    short = IMF,
    long  = Intrinsic Mode Function,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{MCSA}{
    short = MCSA,
    long  = Motor Current Signature Analysis,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{PCA}{
    short = PCA,
    long  = Principal Component Analysis,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{PWM}{
    short = PWM,
    long  = Pulse Width Modulation,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{REB}{
    short = REB,
    long  = Roller Element Bearing,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RFI}{
    short = RFI,
    long  = Radio Frequency Interference,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RMS}{
    short = RMS,
    long  = Root Mean Square,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RPFI}{
    short = RPFI,
    long  = Roller Pass Frequency Inner-Race,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RPFO}{
    short = RPFO,
    long  = Roller Pass Frequency Outer-Race,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RSF}{
    short = RSF,
    long  = Roller Spin Frequency,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{SDSoC}{
    short = SDSoC,
    long  = Software Defined System on Chip,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{SoC}{
    short = SoC,
    long  = System on Chip,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{STFT}{
    short = STFT,
    long  = Short-Time Fourier Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{SVM}{
    short = SVM,
    long  = Support Vector Machine,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{VLSI}{
    short = VLSI,
    long  = Very Large Scale Integration,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{VHDL}{
    short = VHDL,
    long  = VHSIC Hardware Description Language,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{VHSIC}{
    short = VHSIC,
    long  = Very High Speed Integrated Circuit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{WPT}{
    short = WPT,
    long  = Wavelet Packet Transform,
    class = abbrev}

%%% Symbols

%% Regular Alphabet
\DeclareAcronym{b}{
    short = \ensuremath{b},
    long  = Dyadic Translation,
    sort  = 0002,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{c}{
    short = \ensuremath{c},
    long  = Speed of Sound,
    sort  = 0003,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{EffElas}{
    short = \ensuremath{E},
    long  = Effective Elastic Modulus,
    sort  = 0005,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{g}{
    short = \ensuremath{g},
    long  = High-Pass Filter (Wavelet Transform),
    sort  = 0007,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{h}{
    short = \ensuremath{h},
    long  = Low-Pass Filter (Wavelet Transform),
    sort  = 0008,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Ks}{
    short = \ensuremath{K_{s}},
    long  = Bulk Modulus,
    sort  = 0011,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{m}{
    short = \ensuremath{m},
    long  = Mass,
    sort  = 0012,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{M}{
    short = \ensuremath{M},
    long  = Molecular Mass,
    sort  = 0012.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{P}{
    short = \ensuremath{P},
    long  = Pressure,
    sort  = 0015,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{CPV}{
    short = \ensuremath{CPV},
    long  = Cauchy Principle Value,
    sort  = 0015.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{v}{
    short = \ensuremath{v},
    long  = Velocity,
    sort  = 0021,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{V}{
    short = \ensuremath{V},
    long  = Volume,
    sort  = 0021.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Wab}{
    short = \ensuremath{W_{(\alpha,b)}},
    long  = Wavelet Coefficients,
    sort  = 0022,
    class = nomencl}

%% Greek Alphabet
\DeclareAcronym{alpha}{
    short = \ensuremath{\alpha},
    long  = Dyadic Dilation,
    sort  = 1001,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{beta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\beta},
    long  = Beta,
    sort  = 1002,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{gamma}{
    short = \ensuremath{\gamma},
    long  = Heat Capacity Ratio,
    sort  = 1003,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{delta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\delta},
    long  = Delta,
    sort  = 1004,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{epsilon}{
    short = \ensuremath{\epsilon},
    long  = Epsilon,
    sort  = 1005,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varepsilon}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varepsilon},
    long  = Varepsilon,
    sort  = 1006,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{zeta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\zeta},
    long  = Zeta,
    sort  = 1007,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{eta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\eta},
    long  = Eta,
    sort  = 1008,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{theta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\theta},
    long  = Angle,
    sort  = 1009,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{vartheta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\vartheta},
    long  = Vartheta,
    sort  = 1010,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Theta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\Theta},
    long  = Cap Theta,
    sort  = 1011,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{iota}{
    short = \ensuremath{\iota},
    long  = Iota,
    sort  = 1012,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{kappa}{
    short = \ensuremath{\kappa},
    long  = Kappa,
    sort  = 1013,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{lambda}{
    short = \ensuremath{\lambda},
    long  = Wavelength,
    sort  = 1014,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Lambda}{
    short = \ensuremath{\Lambda},
    long  = Lambda,
    sort  = 1015,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{mu}{
    short = \ensuremath{\mu},
    long  = mu,
    sort  = 1016,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{nu}{
    short = \ensuremath{\nu},
    long  = nu,
    sort  = 1017,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{xi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\xi},
    long  = xi,
    sort  = 1018,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{rho}{
    short = \ensuremath{\rho},
    long  = Density,
    sort  = 1021,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varrho}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varrho},
    long  = varrho,
    sort  = 1022,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{sigma}{
    short = \ensuremath{\sigma},
    long  = sigma,
    sort  = 1023,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varsigma}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varsigma},
    long  = varsigma,
    sort  = 1024,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{tau}{
    short = \ensuremath{\tau},
    long  = tau,
    sort  = 1025,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{upsilon}{
    short = \ensuremath{\upsilon},
    long  = upsilon,
    sort  = 1026,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{phi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\phi},
    long  = phi,
    sort  = 1027,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varphiphase}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varphi},
    long  = Phase,
    sort  = 1028,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varphiwavelet}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varphi},
    long  = Dyadic Dilation Function,
    sort  = 1028.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varPhi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varPhi},
    long  = varPhi,
    sort  = 1029,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{chi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\chi},
    long  = chi,
    sort  = 1030,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{psi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\psi},
    long  = Analysing Wavelet / Mother Wavelet,
    sort  = 1031,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varPsi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varPsi},
    long  = varPsi,
    sort  = 1032,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{omega}{
    short = \ensuremath{\omega},
    long  = Angular Frequency,
    sort  = 1033,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Omega}{
    short = \ensuremath{\Omega},
    long  = Omega,
    sort  = 1034,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varOmega}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varOmega},
    long  = varOmega,
    sort  = 1035,
    class = nomencl}



\begin{document}

    \chapter*{Nomenclature}

    \section*{Abbreviations}
%   \begin{flushleft}
%       \begin{footnotesize}
%           \begin{multicols}{2}
                \printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev, heading=none]
%           \end{multicols}
%       \end{footnotesize}
%   \end{flushleft}

    \newpage
    \section*{Characters \& Symbols}
%   \begin{flushleft}
%       \begin{footnotesize}
%           \begin{multicols}{2}
                \printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl, heading=none]
%           \end{multicols}
%       \end{footnotesize}
%   \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Second set is nice and aligned but won't work with multi-column.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you might want to keep in mind that the `hyperref` package should generally be loaded last. (One of the few exceptions in the `cleveref` package).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use the following style that is adapted from the example in page 37 of the `acro` package manual:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=25mm, bottom=27mm, left=35mm, right=30mm, bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}


\usepackage[hyperref = true, only-used = false, list-style = longtable]{acro}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem} %allows itemize environment adjustments
\usepackage{multicol}


\newlist{acronyms}{description}{1}
\setlist[acronyms]{
labelwidth = 4.5em,
leftmargin = 5em,
noitemsep,
itemindent = 0pt}
\DeclareAcroListStyle{mystyle}{list}{ list = acronyms }
\acsetup{ list-style = mystyle }

%%% Nomenclature Definitions

%%% Acronyms
\DeclareAcronym{ADC}{
    short = ADC,
    long  = Analogue to Digital Converter,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{AE}{
    short = AE,
    long  = Acoustic Emission,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{AI}{
    short = AI,
    long  = Artificial Intelligence,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{ANN}{
    short = ANN,
    long  = Artificial Neural Network,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{ACTMS}{
    short = ACTMS,
    long  = Acoustic Combustion Turbine Monitoring System,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{ASIC}{
    short = ASIC,
    long  = Application Specific Integrated Circuit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{BLDC}{
    short = BLDC,
    long  = BrushLess Direct Current,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{CWT}{
    short = CWT,
    long  = Continuous Wavelet Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DAC}{
    short = DAC,
    long  = Digital to Analogue Converter,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DFT}{
    short = DFT,
    long  = Discrete Fourier Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DSP}{
    short = DSP,
    long  = Digital Signal Processing / Processor,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{DWT}{
    short = DWT,
    long  = Discrete Wavelet Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{EEMD}{
    short = EEMD,
    long  = Ensemble Empirical Mode Decomposition,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{EMD}{
    short = EMD,
    long  = Empirical Mode Decomposition,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{EMI}{
    short = EMI,
    long  = Electromagnetic Interference,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{FFT}{
    short = FFT,
    long  = Fast Fourier Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{FPGA}{
    short = FPGA,
    long  = Field-Programmable Gate Array,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{FTF}{
    short = FTF,
    long  = Fundamental Train Frequency,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{GenPU}{
    short = GPU,
    long  = General Processing Unit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{GraPU}{
    short = GPU,
    long  = Graphics Processing Unit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{HDL}{
    short = HDL,
    long  = Hardware Description Language,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{HHT}{
    short = HHT,
    long  = Hilbert-Huang Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{IDE}{
    short = IDE,
    long  = Integrated Development Environment,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{IMF}{
    short = IMF,
    long  = Intrinsic Mode Function,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{MCSA}{
    short = MCSA,
    long  = Motor Current Signature Analysis,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{PCA}{
    short = PCA,
    long  = Principal Component Analysis,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{PWM}{
    short = PWM,
    long  = Pulse Width Modulation,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{REB}{
    short = REB,
    long  = Roller Element Bearing,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RFI}{
    short = RFI,
    long  = Radio Frequency Interference,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RMS}{
    short = RMS,
    long  = Root Mean Square,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RPFI}{
    short = RPFI,
    long  = Roller Pass Frequency Inner-Race,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RPFO}{
    short = RPFO,
    long  = Roller Pass Frequency Outer-Race,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{RSF}{
    short = RSF,
    long  = Roller Spin Frequency,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{SDSoC}{
    short = SDSoC,
    long  = Software Defined System on Chip,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{SoC}{
    short = SoC,
    long  = System on Chip,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{STFT}{
    short = STFT,
    long  = Short-Time Fourier Transform,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{SVM}{
    short = SVM,
    long  = Support Vector Machine,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{VLSI}{
    short = VLSI,
    long  = Very Large Scale Integration,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{VHDL}{
    short = VHDL,
    long  = VHSIC Hardware Description Language,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{VHSIC}{
    short = VHSIC,
    long  = Very High Speed Integrated Circuit,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{WPT}{
    short = WPT,
    long  = Wavelet Packet Transform,
    class = abbrev}

%%% Symbols

%% Regular Alphabet
\DeclareAcronym{b}{
    short = \ensuremath{b},
    long  = Dyadic Translation,
    sort  = 0002,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{c}{
    short = \ensuremath{c},
    long  = Speed of Sound,
    sort  = 0003,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{EffElas}{
    short = \ensuremath{E},
    long  = Effective Elastic Modulus,
    sort  = 0005,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{g}{
    short = \ensuremath{g},
    long  = High-Pass Filter (Wavelet Transform),
    sort  = 0007,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{h}{
    short = \ensuremath{h},
    long  = Low-Pass Filter (Wavelet Transform),
    sort  = 0008,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Ks}{
    short = \ensuremath{K_{s}},
    long  = Bulk Modulus,
    sort  = 0011,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{m}{
    short = \ensuremath{m},
    long  = Mass,
    sort  = 0012,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{M}{
    short = \ensuremath{M},
    long  = Molecular Mass,
    sort  = 0012.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{P}{
    short = \ensuremath{P},
    long  = Pressure,
    sort  = 0015,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{CPV}{
    short = \ensuremath{CPV},
    long  = Cauchy Principle Value,
    sort  = 0015.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{v}{
    short = \ensuremath{v},
    long  = Velocity,
    sort  = 0021,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{V}{
    short = \ensuremath{V},
    long  = Volume,
    sort  = 0021.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Wab}{
    short = \ensuremath{W_{(\alpha,b)}},
    long  = Wavelet Coefficients,
    sort  = 0022,
    class = nomencl}

%% Greek Alphabet
\DeclareAcronym{alpha}{
    short = \ensuremath{\alpha},
    long  = Dyadic Dilation,
    sort  = 1001,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{beta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\beta},
    long  = Beta,
    sort  = 1002,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{gamma}{
    short = \ensuremath{\gamma},
    long  = Heat Capacity Ratio,
    sort  = 1003,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{delta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\delta},
    long  = Delta,
    sort  = 1004,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{epsilon}{
    short = \ensuremath{\epsilon},
    long  = Epsilon,
    sort  = 1005,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varepsilon}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varepsilon},
    long  = Varepsilon,
    sort  = 1006,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{zeta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\zeta},
    long  = Zeta,
    sort  = 1007,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{eta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\eta},
    long  = Eta,
    sort  = 1008,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{theta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\theta},
    long  = Angle,
    sort  = 1009,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{vartheta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\vartheta},
    long  = Vartheta,
    sort  = 1010,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Theta}{
    short = \ensuremath{\Theta},
    long  = Cap Theta,
    sort  = 1011,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{iota}{
    short = \ensuremath{\iota},
    long  = Iota,
    sort  = 1012,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{kappa}{
    short = \ensuremath{\kappa},
    long  = Kappa,
    sort  = 1013,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{lambda}{
    short = \ensuremath{\lambda},
    long  = Wavelength,
    sort  = 1014,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Lambda}{
    short = \ensuremath{\Lambda},
    long  = Lambda,
    sort  = 1015,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{mu}{
    short = \ensuremath{\mu},
    long  = mu,
    sort  = 1016,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{nu}{
    short = \ensuremath{\nu},
    long  = nu,
    sort  = 1017,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{xi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\xi},
    long  = xi,
    sort  = 1018,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{rho}{
    short = \ensuremath{\rho},
    long  = Density,
    sort  = 1021,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varrho}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varrho},
    long  = varrho,
    sort  = 1022,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{sigma}{
    short = \ensuremath{\sigma},
    long  = sigma,
    sort  = 1023,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varsigma}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varsigma},
    long  = varsigma,
    sort  = 1024,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{tau}{
    short = \ensuremath{\tau},
    long  = tau,
    sort  = 1025,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{upsilon}{
    short = \ensuremath{\upsilon},
    long  = upsilon,
    sort  = 1026,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{phi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\phi},
    long  = phi,
    sort  = 1027,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varphiphase}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varphi},
    long  = Phase,
    sort  = 1028,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varphiwavelet}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varphi},
    long  = Dyadic Dilation Function,
    sort  = 1028.5,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varPhi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varPhi},
    long  = varPhi,
    sort  = 1029,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{chi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\chi},
    long  = chi,
    sort  = 1030,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{psi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\psi},
    long  = Analysing Wavelet / Mother Wavelet,
    sort  = 1031,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varPsi}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varPsi},
    long  = varPsi,
    sort  = 1032,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{omega}{
    short = \ensuremath{\omega},
    long  = Angular Frequency,
    sort  = 1033,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Omega}{
    short = \ensuremath{\Omega},
    long  = Omega,
    sort  = 1034,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{varOmega}{
    short = \ensuremath{\varOmega},
    long  = varOmega,
    sort  = 1035,
    class = nomencl}



\begin{document}

    \chapter*{Nomenclature}

    \section*{Abbreviations}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{footnotesize}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev, heading=none]
            \end{multicols}
        \end{footnotesize}
    \end{flushleft}

    \newpage
    \section*{Characters \& Symbols}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{footnotesize}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl, heading=none]
            \end{multicols}
        \end{footnotesize}
    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @leandriis. Great solution. Cheers.

Comment: @leandriis in getting following error if I use your code. Can you help me.? ```Package acro Error: The command \DeclareAcroListStyle has been removed. \DeclareAcroListStyle```.

Comment: With the release of verion 3 of the `acro` package quite some changes with regard to the user inderface were added. Aparently `\DeclareAcroListStyle` can no longer be used with version 3 of the `acro` package.

Comment: @Keerthivasan sounds like you may want to try `\usepackage[version=2]{acro}`.