# Multi-column, aligned acronym list with acro package (article class and acro version 3.x)

Tags: lists, multicolumn, acro

To make a long story short, I have the same question as already mentioned in [acro 3.3 format listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573654/acro-3-3-format-listing) and [How to make a multi-column acronym list with acro package, aligned and with short definition in bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498761/how-to-make-a-multi-column-acronym-list-with-acro-package-aligned-and-with-shor).

The first solution needs KOMA script and I have to stay on article class. The second solution looks 100% like I want but it is for acro package version 2. Is there a solution for acro version 3 and article class?

tl;dr: Here is a MWE. As already mentioned in the two other questions, longtable and multicolumn not working together and with the default description style from acro package the tabs are missing.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=25mm, bottom=27mm, left=35mm, right=30mm, bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{acro}

%%% Acronyms
\DeclareAcronym{ADC}{short = ADC, long = Analogue to Digital Converter}
\DeclareAcronym{AE}{short = AE, long = Acoustic Emission}
\DeclareAcronym{AI}{short = AI, long = Artificial Intelligence}
\DeclareAcronym{ANN}{short = ANN, long = Artificial Neural Network}
\DeclareAcronym{ACTMS}{short = ACTMS, long = Acoustic Combustion Turbine Monitoring System}
\DeclareAcronym{ASIC}{short = ASIC, long = Application Specific Integrated Circuit}
\DeclareAcronym{BLDC}{short = BLDC, long = BrushLess Direct Current}
\DeclareAcronym{CWT}{short = CWT, long = Continuous Wavelet Transform}
\DeclareAcronym{DAC}{short = DAC, long = Digital to Analogue Converter}
\DeclareAcronym{DFT}{short = DFT, long = Discrete Fourier Transform}
\DeclareAcronym{DSP}{short = DSP, long = Digital Signal Processing / Processor}
\DeclareAcronym{DWT}{short = DWT, long = Discrete Wavelet Transform}
\DeclareAcronym{EEMD}{short = EEMD, long = Ensemble Empirical Mode Decomposition}
\DeclareAcronym{EMD}{short = EMD, long = Empirical Mode Decomposition}
\DeclareAcronym{EMI}{short = EMI, long = Electromagnetic Interference}
\DeclareAcronym{FFT}{short = FFT, long = Fast Fourier Transform}
\DeclareAcronym{FPGA}{short = FPGA, long = Field-Programmable Gate Array}
\DeclareAcronym{FTF}{short = FTF, long = Fundamental Train Frequency}
\DeclareAcronym{GenPU}{short = GPU, long = General Processing Unit}
\DeclareAcronym{GraPU}{short = GPU, long = Graphics Processing Unit}
\DeclareAcronym{HDL}{short = HDL, long = Hardware Description Language}
\DeclareAcronym{HHT}{short = HHT, long = Hilbert-Huang Transform}
\DeclareAcronym{IDE}{short = IDE, long = Integrated Development Environment}
\DeclareAcronym{IMF}{short = IMF, long = Intrinsic Mode Function}
\DeclareAcronym{MCSA}{short = MCSA, long = Motor Current Signature Analysis}
\DeclareAcronym{PCA}{short = PCA, long = Principal Component Analysis}
\DeclareAcronym{PWM}{short = PWM, long = Pulse Width Modulation}
\DeclareAcronym{REB}{short = REB, long = Roller Element Bearing}
\DeclareAcronym{RFI}{short = RFI, long = Radio Frequency Interference}
\DeclareAcronym{RMS}{short = RMS, long = Root Mean Square}
\DeclareAcronym{RPFI}{short = RPFI, long = Roller Pass Frequency Inner-Race}
\DeclareAcronym{RPFO}{short = RPFO, long = Roller Pass Frequency Outer-Race}
\DeclareAcronym{RSF}{short = RSF, long = Roller Spin Frequency}
\DeclareAcronym{SDSoC}{short = SDSoC, long = Software Defined System on Chip}
\DeclareAcronym{SoC}{short = SoC, long = System on Chip}
\DeclareAcronym{STFT}{short = STFT, long = Short-Time Fourier Transform}
\DeclareAcronym{SVM}{short = SVM, long = Support Vector Machine}
\DeclareAcronym{VLSI}{short = VLSI, long = Very Large Scale Integration}
\DeclareAcronym{VHDL}{short = VHDL, long = VHSIC Hardware Description Language}
\DeclareAcronym{VHSIC}{short = VHSIC, long = Very High Speed Integrated Circuit}
\DeclareAcronym{WPT}{short = WPT, long = Wavelet Packet Transform}
\DeclareAcronym{nbiot}{short = NB-IoT, long=Narrow-band IoT}
\DeclareAcronym{iot}{short = IoT, long=Internet of Things}
\DeclareAcronym{uart}{short = UART, long=Universal Asynchronous Receiver Transmitter}
\DeclareAcronym{spi}{short = SPI, long=Serial Peripheral Interface}
\DeclareAcronym{miso}{short = MISO, long=Master In Slave Out}
\DeclareAcronym{mosi}{short = MOSI, long=Master Out Slave In}
\DeclareAcronym{aes}{short = AES, long=Advanced Encryption Standard}
\DeclareAcronym{ide}{short = IDE, long=Integrated Development Environment}
\DeclareAcronym{eda}{short = EDA, long=Electronic Design Automation}
\DeclareAcronym{cmac}{short = CMAC, long=Cipher-based Message Authentication Code}
\DeclareAcronym{pla}{short = PLA, long=Polylactide}
\DeclareAcronym{petg}{short = PETG, long=Polyethylenterephthalat-Glycol}
\DeclareAcronym{adc}{short = ADC, long=Analog Digital Converter}
\DeclareAcronym{msb}{short = MSB, long=Most Significant Bit}
\DeclareAcronym{lsb}{short = LSB, long=Least Significant Bit}
\DeclareAcronym{bom}{short = BOM, long=Bill of Materials}
\DeclareAcronym{eeprom}{short = EEPROM, long=Electrically Erasable Programmable Read-Only Memory}
\DeclareAcronym{vpb}{short = VPB, long=Volts per Bit}
\DeclareAcronym{i2c}{short = I²C, long=Inter-Integrated Circuit}
\DeclareAcronym{json}{short = JSON, long=JavaScript Object Notation}
\DeclareAcronym{xml}{short = XML, long=Extensible Markup Language}
\DeclareAcronym{isr}{short = ISR, long=Interrupt Service Routine}
\DeclareAcronym{gpio}{short = GPIO, long=General Purpose Input/Output} 
\DeclareAcronym{pwm}{short = PWM, long=Pulse-width modulation} 
\DeclareAcronym{ldo}{short = LDO, long=Low Drop-Out} 
\DeclareAcronym{rest}{short = REST, long=Representational State Transfer} 
\DeclareAcronym{mqtt}{short = MQTT, long=Message Queuing Telemetry Transport} 
\DeclareAcronym{pcb}{short = PCB, long=Printed Circuit Board} 
\DeclareAcronym{dmm}{short = DMM, long=Digitalmultimeter} 
\DeclareAcronym{bod}{short = BOD, long=Brown-out Detection} 
\DeclareAcronym{ppk2}{short = PPK2, long=Power Profiler Kit II} 
\DeclareAcronym{dut}{short = DUT, long=Device Under Test} 
\DeclareAcronym{bos}{short = BOS, long=Behörden und Organisationen mit Sicherheitsaufgaben} 
\DeclareAcronym{fft}{short = FFT, long=Fast Fourier Transform} 
\DeclareAcronym{isp}{short = ISP, long=Internet Service Provider} 
\DeclareAcronym{ber}{short = BER, long=Bit Error Rate} 
\DeclareAcronym{spof}{short = SPOF, long=Single Point of Failure} 
\DeclareAcronym{mcu}{short = MCU, long=Microcontroller}
\DeclareAcronym{dect}{short = DECT, long=Digital Enhanced Cordless Telecommunications}


\usepackage{multicol}

\acsetup{
    list/display = all,
    first-style=short-long,
    list/heading=none,
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
 \printacronyms
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm just not seeing it but there is no need for a KOMA-Script class in either answer. In my answer to [acro 3.3 format listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573654/) I mentioned that the `labeling` environment is available for all classes by loading the `scrextend` package.

Anyway, it's quite easy to use the list defined with `enumitem` from @leandriis' answer to [How to make a multi-column acronym list with acro package, aligned and with short definition in bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498761/) with the solution from [acro 3.3 format listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573654/) – just replace the `labeling` environment with the `acronyms` environment:

```
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}

\newlist{acronyms}{description}{1}
\setlist[acronyms]{
  labelwidth = 4.5em,
  leftmargin = 5em,
  noitemsep,
  itemindent = 0pt
}

\NewAcroTemplate[list]{twocolumn}{%
  \begin{multicols}{2}[\acroheading]
    \acropreamble
    \begin{acronyms}
      \acronymsmapF
        {\item[\bfseries\acrowrite{short}] \acrowrite{list}}
        {\item\AcroRerun}
    \end{acronyms}
  \end{multicols}
}
```